# Button doesn't work in my Activity

Tags: android, button

This is my Activity

```
public class PetRegistrationActivity extends Activity {


private Button born;
private Button take;
private Date date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_registration);
    final Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_info_button);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {

            performSave();

        }
    });
}

private void performSave() {
    Pet p = new Pet();
    date = new Date(p,R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob,
            R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover,
            this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            PetRegistrationActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
    born = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob);
    take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
    date.buildPicker(p, R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob,
            R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
    date.buildPicker(p, R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover,
            R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
    DataHelper.getInstance().storeImage(this.selectedImg,
            getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(p.getId()));

    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent(PetRegistrationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.NEW_PET, p);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    this.finish();

}
```

}

And this is the code of Class Date:

```
public class Date {

private final IPickerHelper picker;
private final int id;
private final int secondID;
private final View v;
private final Context ctx;
private Button dateButton;
private SimpleDateFormat fmt;

public Date(IPickerHelper picker, int id, int secondID,View v,Context ctx){
    this.picker = picker;
    this.id = id;
    this.secondID = secondID;
    this.v = v;
    this.ctx = ctx;

}

public void buildPicker(final IPickerHelper pickerObj,
                        final int buttonId, final int secondButtonId) {

    dateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(buttonId);
    fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ITALIAN);


    if (pickerObj.getStartDate() == null) {
        final java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        pickerObj.setStartDate(date);
        pickerObj.setEndDate(date);
        dateButton.setText(fmt.format(date));
    } else {
        dateButton.setText(fmt.format(pickerObj.getStartDate()));
        final Button endingButton = (Button) v.findViewById(secondButtonId);
        endingButton.setText(fmt.format(pickerObj.getEndDate()));
    }

    dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            final java.util.Date value = new java.util.Date();
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(value);
            if (secondButtonId == -1) {
                setTimePickerDialog(pickerObj, buttonId);
            } else {
                setDatePickerDialog(pickerObj, buttonId, cal, fmt);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setDatePickerDialog(final IPickerHelper pickerObj, final int buttonId,
                                 final Calendar cal, final SimpleDateFormat fmt) {

    new DatePickerDialog(ctx, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(final DatePicker view, final int y, final int m, final int d) {
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);

            final Button dateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(buttonId);

            if (buttonId == R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob) {
                pickerObj.setStartDate(cal.getTime());
                final Button endingButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
                endingButton.setText(fmt.format(cal.getTime()));
            } else {
                pickerObj.setEndDate(cal.getTime());
            }
            dateButton.setText(fmt.format(cal.getTime()));
        }

    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

}

The two buttons (born and take) do nothing when I click them.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

put the following inside `onCreate` :

```
born = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob);
take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
```

Comment: My pleasure, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Move these two lines inside `onCreate`, as @Bouterbiat already noticed. But also don't forget to add the **listeners** for these two buttons, that's what you had not done in your code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_registration);
    final Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_info_button);
    born = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_dob);
    take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalinfo_datepicker_takeover);
    born.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(final View arg0) {

        //Do whatever born does
       }
    });
    take.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(final View arg0) {

        //Do whatever take does
       }
    });
```